# What happens at the end of NightHunter?

Tags: atari-2600

Ok, so this is a question brought to you by the wayback machine.

There used to be a game on the Atari something-or-other that was called "NightHunter". In it, you played Dracula as he wandered around and kicked some ass murdering and looting through some town.

You could turn into a giant bear-monster (i think it was a very liberal interpretation of the "werewolf" concept) and a little bat.

Anyway, I played this game years ago - about 23? 24? And I recall enjoying it, but I also never finished the game. I think you had to get medallions for some reason? I don't think the reason involved a fashion show.

As it happens I'm tearing my hair out over some stupid computer programming nonsense and thought I'd kill some time checking if anyone remembers the game, knows what happened in the end or maybe, just maybe, knows if there is some newer-version of it out and about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NightHunter was a game released by a little French studio called "Ubisoft" in 1988.  You may have played [some of their other titles.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubisoft_games)   A version was available for the Atari ST, as well as a couple of other platforms, including the Commodore 64 and the PC.

The levels start to repeat after a while, with the difficulty going up due to harder enemies - fewer defenseless blondes and more arrow-firing vampire hunters.

The final level is level 30, and it's the same as level 5 aside from the difficulty.  Completing it gets you here:

... a blue "GAME OVER" screen with a high score list.  :(  (Do note that this is from the PC version of the game - it's the best I can do!)

Playing it today would require a version of the original game along with some sort of emulator.  There was a PC version, so getting that and something like [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) would probably be the easiest way to go.  As far as I can tell, it's not a property they've invested considerable time in since the 80's.  Alternatively, it looks as if this particular YouTube user has done a walkthrough of the entire game, so just watching that might give you enough of a NightHunter fix.

Comment: thanks! i really just missed the title music, but i found that on youtube.  The ending on the PC (and probably the Atari) is pretty bad.